# NextJS: Error: You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack, next.js

My NextJS application is as follows:

app/page.js

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';

export default function Home() {
   return (<div>Testing</div>);
}
```

app/layout.js

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Next.js',
  description: 'Generated by Next.js',
}
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
 return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

When I run

```
next dev
```

I get the following error:

```
error - node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/module-proxy.js (56:14) @ Object.get
error - Error: Cannot access default.then on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
null
error - node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/module-proxy.js (56:14) @ Object.get
error - Error: Cannot access default.then on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

I can't find any reference to default.then. Is there any way this error can be narrowed down? I haven't been able to find this error on a web search so any information on the error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade your next.js version with  13.4.19 (latest) if not being used.

Comment: That ended up fixing it. Although I would like to know what the error means so that it's documented, since there isn't any documentation that I could find. Also if the problem shows up in a later version upgrading may not be an option.

Comment: @ClusterH if you write an answer that says this, I'll go ahead and select it as the answer.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can upgrade your next.js version with `13.4.19` or `latest` if you are using old versions. Here is [Next.js Official docs to upgrade your application](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading)

Comment: I'm still having this in 13.5.4

Comment: I am also still having this issue on 13.5.6

Comment: I'm having this issue on `13.4.19`.

Answer (score 1):

On Next 13.5.2, similar error message, though not Promise related.

> "Cannot access ChildComponent.propTypes on the server."

Really straightforward setup. Parent component is a RSC. Child is 'use client':

```
<Wrapper>
   <ChildComponent/>
</Wrapper>
```

In my case, I isolated the issue to the type of import/export

The error occurs when the child is imported as a named export. Export the child as default export and the issue disappears.

Adding defaults to every component used in this way won't be feasible for many, so not ideal, but it's the best I've got.